# Arrayformula listing based on checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets

In my sheet have column A with checkboxes and column B with Country Names. In Column C I want an arrayformula to list all checked countries. I'm using the following formula, but the unchecked countries appear as FALSE. I want to skip the unchecked countries and just have a continuous list of checked countries with no falses or empty cells. What should I do?

```
={"COUNTRY";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"";IF(A2:A=true;B2:B);""))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this formula:

=FILTER(B2:B,A2:A=TRUE)

[image]